# Normal number and Kolmogorov complexity

Tags: real-analysis, kolmogorov-complexity, algorithmic-randomness

For real number $r$, infinite sequence of its digits in base 10, (I mean 1/9=>1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1.....)

I heard that if this sequence is the random sequence in the sense of kolmogorov complexity theory, then such $r$ is normal number. Is it right? Then how to prove it?

Comment: I am not very experienced in this subject, but it seems to me that if there is some sequence in some base that never appears (i.e. $r$ is not normal), then you can build a machine or write a programming language that uses that exact sequence to code for something longer (i.e. $r$ is not random).

Comment: The reason is essentially the same as in this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008886/why-is-chaitins-constant-absolutely-normal - the assumption of incompressibility is the same as [Martin-Löf randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmically_random_sequence#Three_equivalent_definitions)